# how to set a four dimension variable in docplex with python?

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I want to set a binary four-dimensions variable, like X[a][b][c][d], bur docplex only have function  `binary_var_cube` to set a three-dimension. How can I to create a four-dimension?
I have found that someone use this to create a three-dimension and said it could extend to more dimensions.But it isn't useful.

```py
binary_var_dict((a,b,c) for a in ... for b in ... for c in ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me share a tiny example:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# Data

r=range(1,3)

i=[(a,b,c,d) for a in r for b in r for c in r for d in r]

print(i)

mdl = Model(name='model')

#decision variables
mdl.x=mdl.integer_var_dict(i,name="x")

# Constraint
for it in i:
    mdl.add_constraint(mdl.x[it] == it[0]+it[1]+it[2]+it[3], 'ct')

mdl.solve()

# Dislay solution
for it in i:
    print(" x ",it," --> ",mdl.x[it].solution_value);
```

which gives

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2)]
 x  (1, 1, 1, 1)  -->  4.0
 x  (1, 1, 1, 2)  -->  5.0
 x  (1, 1, 2, 1)  -->  5.0
 x  (1, 1, 2, 2)  -->  6.0
 x  (1, 2, 1, 1)  -->  5.0
 x  (1, 2, 1, 2)  -->  6.0
 x  (1, 2, 2, 1)  -->  6.0
 x  (1, 2, 2, 2)  -->  7.0
 x  (2, 1, 1, 1)  -->  5.0
 x  (2, 1, 1, 2)  -->  6.0
 x  (2, 1, 2, 1)  -->  6.0
 x  (2, 1, 2, 2)  -->  7.0
 x  (2, 2, 1, 1)  -->  6.0
 x  (2, 2, 1, 2)  -->  7.0
 x  (2, 2, 2, 1)  -->  7.0
 x  (2, 2, 2, 2)  -->  8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer from Daniel Junglas, copied almost verbatim from https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/385771/decision-matrices-with-more-than-3-variables-for-d/

You can use tuples of any arity as keys to access the variables from a dictionary:

```
 x = m.binary_var_dict((i, l, t, v, r)
                       for i in types
                       for l in locations
                       for t in times
                       for v in vehicles
                       for r in routes)
```

You can then access the variables using:

```
for i in types:
    for l in locations:
       for t in times:
          for v in vehicles:
             for r in routes:
                print x[i, l, t, v, r]
```

You could as well use:

```
 x = [[[[[m.binary_var('%d_%d_%d_%d_%d' % (i, l, t, v, r))
          for r in routes]
         for v in vehicles]
        for t in times]
       for l in locations]
      for i in types]

 for i in types:
    for l in locations:
       for t in times:
          for v in vehicles:
             for r in routes:
                print x[i][l][t][v][r]
```

but this method doesn't support sparse dimensions, and requires many more brackets to express.

Comment: very thanks your answer ! but how could I set a name to variable X? if I use the first method with five for-loop, I can't set binary_var_dict( var, name=' ')

Comment: As all modeling objects, they have a [`name` property](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/mp/docplex.mp.basic.html).